# Bugs in excel/access external data handling?

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have a sort of "database" set up where I have a primary spreadsheet where most of the data is populated - this links into access through linked tables and then is pulled into another secondary spreadsheet where more information (particularly percentage information) is added.

This data is then fed again into access through linked tables and is again passed into a tertiary spreadsheet which uses the percentages from the second sheet to calculate values .

However there appears to be a bug of sorts somewhere in the sheets which I suspect is a data type issue.

When I "refresh all" in the tertiary spreadsheet - all the links refresh however the data feed from the second spreadsheet sometimes 0's out. I can pinpoint some exact examples where 0.5 becomes 0. This greatly affects the data as it appears that values "drop out".

However, if I go to the data source in the third sheet, right click the table and click refresh, the values return to normal - which absolutely drives me insane as it instills a lack of confidence in the "system".

Is this a bug?

Things I have tried:

- Formatting the source values as numbers or percentages - no change
- Formatting the data in Access SQL - FORMAT([Data],"Number") - no change
- Using Access - before I had the excel sheets directly linked to each other     through MS Query.

Answer (score 0):

Are there cross-dependencies in your third datasheet? Perhaps the "refresh all" is "optimized" in chunks, so some of your data is depending on data that has not yet been populated.

Without speculating further, it would be helpful for you to include some screenshots of your issue and process.